# wireless connection get listed as eth1 + UNIX + MacoX

Tags: linux, macos, wireless-networking, ethernet

I'm not sure what is the best word to put forward for this since I'm connected to my wireless router and by that definition I was assuming the **ifconfig** to list my ip in **wlan0** section but it display the my ip in en1 section

I'm pretty lame to understand this

Here my ifconfig output

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=2b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,TSO4>
    ether 3c:07:54:3d:e7:3e 
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether b8:8d:12:33:d2:d0 
    inet6 fe80::ba8d:12ff:fe33:d2d0%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
    inet 192.168.1.111 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr a4:b1:97:ff:fe:96:28:e2 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0a:8d:12:33:d2:d0 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
tun0: flags=8851<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.15.2 --> 10.0.15.2 netmask 0xffffff00 
    open (pid 47846)
```

I see something similar behavior in an Ubuntu machine as well so any luck with eth0:1 display the wireless configuration

Any Reference for me to understand this

Answer (score 1):

Different Unix-like OSes have different conventions for low-level interface naming.

OS X calls all Ethernet-like interfaces "enX". When 802.11 wireless Ethernet chipsets first appeared, they presented themselves to host OSes as Ethernet interfaces, because those OSes didn't have any special 802.11-specific support built-in. So on OS X, 802.11 wireless Ethernet interfaces were called enX just like wired Ethernet interfaces, and the name has stuck ever since.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't much any reference for standard "interface name" formats (like "en0", etc.).  Perhaps like you, I've always assumed "en" was short for Ethernet, and perhaps it once was.  However, wi-fi connections will show up as "en" interfaces too, at least on my Mac minis.  If you use `ifconfig -v`, you'll see that it lists the "type" of connection, "Ethernet" or "Wi-Fi".